# Writing a java file

Tags: java

I keep getting errors in the public static void line and the system.out enter your annual sales.  What I am trying to do is get the user to input annual sales and then get the annual sales by factoring in the fixed salary and commission:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class commission {

    public static void main(String[] args)

            Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in; 
            BufferReader br = new BufferReader(instream);

            System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
            String annual = br.readLine();

            int salary = 75_502_81; 
            int com = 38_28; 
            int compensation = annual * com + salary;

}
```

Comment: You're missing a right paren.  And a left brace.

Comment: This also (as it stands), has nothing to do with writing to a file.

Comment: int should not have special character like _ . please remove it.

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE. I WILL TRY TO TAKE ALL COMMENTS INTO CONSIDERATION TO GET THIS FIXED AND WORKING FOR ME. I HAVE BEEN USING A BOOK FROM BARNES AND NOBLES ALONG WITH YOUTUBE VIDS BUT THOSE ARE NOT HELPING ME SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate issue is a missing open brace (`{`) and an closing parenthesis (`)`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                                       ^--- This is important...
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in); 
                                          ^--- Also important :P
    BufferReader br = new BufferReader(instream);

    System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
    String annual = br.readLine();

    int salary = 75_502_81; 
    int com = 38_28; 
    int compensation = annual * com + salary;
}
```

There's no such class as `BufferReader`, I think you mean `BufferedReader`

There's no such variable `instream` declared in you code, I think you might mean `input`, but `BufferedReader` won't take `input` as a valid input type, so I'm not sure what you intentions are here...

You'll also be receiving warnings about an uncaught `IOException`

You can resolve these through the use of `try-catch`

I'm also curious about what `75_502_81` and `38_28` are suppose to mean?  `int` values can't contain anything other then numeric values...

`annual` is also `String`, meaning you can't perform any mathematical operations on it.

You will need to convert the value to an `int` first...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in ); 
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(instream);
        System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
        String annual = br.readLine();

        int salary = 7550281; 
        int com = 3828; 
        int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * com + salary;

    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm left scratching my head as to why, when

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in ); 
    System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
    String annual = input.nextLine();

    int salary = 7550281; 
    int com = 3828; 
    int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * com + salary;

}
```

Will do the same thing...

Comment: Close.  But that's not all there is to it.

Comment: I did say the "immediate"

Comment: *Touche*.  But even so...

Comment: @Makoto Hopefully filled it out a little more :P

Comment: But the right paren is still missing, which [leaves me with this unresolved tension.](http://xkcd.com/859/)

Comment: @Makoto I'll buy that for a dollar...hopefully picked it up now :P

Comment: I GOT THE IDEAL OF 76_345 FROM A BOOK. NICE TO KNOW I DONT NEED IT FOR BIG NUMBERS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this

```
int compensation = annual * com + salary;
```

Because annual is a String :) you have to parse the String to Integer, maybe like this

```
Integer.parseInt(annual);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I used input from everyone. added what was missing.  took out the buffered, added the parseint and it works!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

The reason for current error is you are missing `right paren. And a left brace` as @Makoto has commented.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");

    int annual = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    int salary = 75_502_81; 
    int com = 38_28; 
    int compensation = annual * com + salary;
    System.out.println(compensation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also a missing closing brace

```
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);<-----
```

and I am not sure if scanner object goes with bufferedreader, it will need a reader object

Answer (score 0):

There are few syntax errors. Try below code it must solve the issue.

```
public class Commission {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
            Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in); 
            System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
            String annual = input.nextLine();

            int salary = 75_502_81; 
            int com = 38_28; 
            int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * com + salary;
            System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );
    }
}
```